# How to cut exactly a plane with a particle system so the particles dont leave the limit area?

Tags: particles

I want to find a way to dont let my particles system outside a delimitation area in that way the grass dont leave the square area, as u can see some are going out of the object [image]

How can i limit the particles to stop at exactly the edge of the square ?

Comment: Why are they going out? Maybe check the origin position of the particle?

Comment: Tried, the origins position are ok. The only thing i could think of is if i down size the particles planes, but in that way i have another problem, that is the particles plane doesn't match the object under him so looks pretty weird

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iLP8B3KcYSmSU4TTYqM2epG-GlZK89bJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes out because of the *Radius* value you've set for the *Children*, which probably means how far (in units) they can go from their parent:

[image]